# How to use input to check if JS object exists

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use the HTML input to check if a javascript object exist? If I type `person` in the form, it should give me an alert saying it exists and it redirects the page. If I type something different, it should get an alert saying that it doesn't exist.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<input id="auth">
<button type="button" onclick="authorize()">Submit</button>

<script>
function authorize(){
var auth;

auth = document.getElementById("auth");
auth = window[auth];

 if (typeof maybeObject !== auth){
  alert("it works");
 }
 else if (typeof maybeObject === auth){
  alert("it doesnt work")
 }


var person = {
    firstName : "Billy",
    lastName  : "Bob",
    age       : 20,
    eyeColor  : "purple"
};


}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `maybeObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval to do what you want and put that in a try catch. But you actually shouldn't do that like that.

```js
function authorize() {
  var auth;

  var person = {
    firstName: "Billy",
    lastName: "Bob",
    age: 20,
    eyeColor: "purple"
  };

  auth = document.getElementById("auth").value;
  try {
    var t = eval(auth);
    alert("exists, hello " + t.firstName);
  } catch (e) {
    alert("doesn't exist");
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="auth">
<button type="button" onclick="authorize()">Submit</button>
```

Better would be something like this, with below you can input the first or lastname of a person, and if it exists you'll get your alert:

```js
function authorize() {
  var auth;

  var persons = [{
    firstName: "Billy",
    lastName: "Bob",
    age: 20,
    eyeColor: "purple"
  }];

  auth = document.getElementById("auth").value;
  if (persons.filter(p => p.firstName == auth || p.lastName == auth).length > 0) {
    alert ("person with that name exists");
  } else {
    alert("no person with given name exists");
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="auth">
<button type="button" onclick="authorize()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: under "if it works", how can I get it to redirect to a different page?

Comment: just add `window.location.href = '<the page you want to go to>'` @AliKesserwani

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work, it just refreshes the page

Comment: It works if you put in a different adress than the one you're currently on

Comment: this is what I'm putting under var t = eval(auth);

Comment: Use a href property... `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'`. However it won't work with google

Comment: I've tried over 10 different links and its not working, are there any other ways?